# layer 2 solution best option

Tags: layer-2

Ive got a client who have his own fork of an evm based chain and is looking for a layer 2 solution for their chain. Open source and easy to use and integrate on their current existing evm based chain, it is a fork of cpp/aleth so it goes without saying technically a full ethereum compatible chain.
whats the best options out there?

Answer (score 1):

For now, I would say the best options still seems to be Polygon. Although it's still a sidechain to be exact, and not yet a layer 2 solution. My reasons for choosing Polygon are:

1. It is still where you have most users and most token liquidity.
2. It's very EVM-friendly and deploying contracts to Polygon would be the exact same process as deploying them to Ethereum testnets or mainnet.

Note: Polygon recently purchased Hermez Network in order to look into implementing ZK-rollups for the network, making it into a fully-fledged layer 2 solution.